# Remove filename.extension in url using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm a beginner in nodejs, so please excuse if this question already answered. I tried multiple methods but didn't work for me.

I'm trying to remove the filename.extension in http url

For example:

http://somedomain.com/path1/path2/path3/myfile.txt

to

http://somedomain.com/path1/path2/path3/

The filename in the url is dynamic, so I cannot use "myfile.txt" explicitly in the code.

I'm not using any web frameworks, But I have http://stringjs.com library

Comment: Will the filename always be the last item in the URL? or could it be in the middle?  If it's always the end, split the string on '/' and drop the last object in the array, then rejoin the strings

Comment: yes, always last in the array. That is a good method. But would like to know any other simple method if any.

Answer (score 3):

**Using a Regular Expression:**

```
'http://somedomain.com/hello1/hello2/hello3/myfile.txt'.replace(/\/\w+\.\w+$/, '');
```

The regular expression matches two strings separated by a `.` and preceeded by a `/` (`/myfile.txt` in your case), which is then being replaced by an empty string. This method works in node as well as in pure javascript.

**Using node.js' `path` module:**

```
let path = require('path');
let parsed = path.parse('http://somedomain.com/hello1/hello2/hello3/myfile.txt');

console.log(parsed.dir) // => http://somedomain.com/hello1/hello2/hello3
```

node.js has a built-in module for parsing paths. It is however not made for parsing URIs, but should work just fine in your case.

**Splitting, Slicing and Joining**

```
let url = 'http://somedomain.com/hello1/hello2/hello3/myfile.txt';

url.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/');
```

Split the url at every `/`, remove the last element from the resulting array (`myfile.txt`) and join them back together with `/` as the separator.

Comment: Just out of interest, which one are you using?

Comment: The last one - split, slice and join :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var path = 'http://somedomain.com/hello1/hello2/hello3/myfile.txt';
path = path.split('/');
path.splice(path.length-1,1);
path = path.join('/');
```